# Why is the creation of multi-dimensional arrays so slow in Scala?

Tags: arrays, performance, scala, compiler-construction

Consider this code:

```
Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

I aborted the REPL after several minutes.

Should I expect such long compilation times or is this a problem/bug of the compiler?

Comment: Could this be called *code*? It's usually the kind of snippets you see on the Daily WTF site.

Comment: Please forgive me for my curiosity, but what exactly does that code do?    Off-the-top of my head, Scala is built on Java, and that's why it's slow.

Comment: @Darin: I was just reading compiler sources and decided to test some corners of it.

Comment: @Adel: That's pretty much wrong.

Comment: Alrighty, I was confused about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Scala 2.9.0.1 this compiles (and runs) just fine as long as you give scalac enough stack space:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-ss128M"
scalac arrays.scala
```

It doesn't seem to work in the REPL though, but that doesn't really surprise me anymore...

Answer (score 6):

Misleading title, I think, at least with respect to the actual code you're trying.

Let's help the type inferencer...

```
object A extends App {
  val x = Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Nothing]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]()
  println(x)
}
```

That compiles just fine and runs just fine (I don't even have to modify JVM options):

```
$ time scalac -d classes A.scala

real    0m5.179s

$ time scala -cp classes A
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[Ljava.lang.Object;@872380

real    0m2.461s
```

So it's more about compilation and type inference including in the REPL (which rewrites the code and recompiles). The REPL seems to struggle somewhere after the explicitrouter phase (tried using `scala -Xprint:all`).